# Is there a way to directly use a property of an enclosing usercontrol in a sqldatasource?

Tags: asp.net, dataview

I have a user control. In that control I have a data view that uses a sql data source. I would like to have one of the parameters to that sql data source be a property of the enclosing user control. The idea is that I want the page that includes the user control to set the property on the user control to the ID of a record, make the user control visible, and now the user sees the data for that record.

I'm thinking that I should be able to have a ControlParameter that references the enclosing user control. But what's the control ID?

I came up with something of a work-around by using a plain Parameter and writing

```
Public Property record_id As Integer
    Get
        Return dsRecord.SelectParameters.Item("rid").DefaultValue
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        dsRecord.SelectParameters.Item("rid").DefaultValue = value
        DetailsView1.DataBind()
    End Set
End Property
```

That works and it isn't all that much code, but it seems kind of ... crude. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: `dsRecord.SelectParameters.Item("rid").DefaultValue = value`  can be shortened to `dsRecord.SelectParameters("rid").DefaultValue = value` and you may not need the `Databind()` in the Set if the control is visible and its `DataSourceID` is set.

Comment: Also, I think a `WriteOnly` property would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `YourDetailsView.DataSourceID="dsRecord"` and it is visible at the time of binding, this may be all you need:

```
  Public WriteOnly Property record_id As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)
      dsRecord.SelectParameters.Item("rid").DefaultValue = value
    End Set
  End Property
```